# How to set the array of checkboxes to checked() in android?

Tags: android, checkbox, radio-button

I have a array of checkboxes `CheckBox labels[] = {fname,lname,company,mobno,workemail,workphone,persemail};`

and I have a radio button. Now what I want is if the user clicks on the radio button, all the check boxes should get checked with the green tick on it.

```
CheckBox labels[] = {fname,lname,company,mobno,workemail,workphone,persemail};  
    RadioButton available,none,privte,publc;
    //String [] values;
    String firstname2,lastname2,comp2,mobileno2,wrkemail2,wrkphone2,persnalemail2;
Button generate;
private String output;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.startnew);
        fname=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.fnamechk);
        lname=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.lnamechk);
        persemail=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.personalemailchk);
        mobno=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.cellchk);
        workemail=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.Workemailchk);
        company=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.companychk);
        workphone=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.workphonechk);

available.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //for(CheckBox cb : labels){ cb.setChecked(true); }

            }
        });
```

Comment: Did you try looping through this array and "setChecked(true)" for each item.

Comment: yes , it is showing null pointer..!!!

Comment: yes, fname=(checkbox)findviewbyid(r.id.fname);

Comment: how are checkboxes created? using XML? can you verify if ids are correct and if they are init before the loop? maybe paste your code so people will not give random answers.. but rather specific to your code..

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this code below?

> for(CheckBox cb : labels){
>       cb.setChecked(true);
>   }

Loop through the CheckBox array and set the checked property to true. I am assuming that the CheckBox array contains object references to the checkboxes.

What I mean is, you have valid references to the UI Checkbox before creating the array.

`CheckBox fname = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.fname);`

Comment: Debug and see if fname is becoming null, also make sure you have an element by this name in the View (layout xml) that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

you can check one at a time ,we cannot select all at a time if you want try to use check-box you can select multiple check-box at a time

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because you have not initialized the `available` variable. You do a `setOnClickListener()` on null item so you are getting `NullPointerException`

Init `available` something like: `available = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.something);` before this line:

```
available.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
...
...
```